# Как установить информационое значение Dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

У меня есть дропдаун, как я могу задать ему информационое значение "Add new Admin"

```
<td class="centered" id="DropDownId">
                @{
                    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> users = new SelectList(Model.Users, "Id", "FullName", Model.AvailableUsers);
                }
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Users, users, "Add new admin", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:200px;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem.AvailableUsers)
            </td>
```

Сейчас у меня стоит дефолтное значение и пользователей может его выбрать и на сервер уходит "Add new Admin" вместо имени админа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Непонятен вопрос. Должно определиться имя текущего пользователя и передаться?

Comment: @codename0082016 Нет, все гораздо проще. У меня есть дропдаун. Я хочу сделать так чтобы информационное значение нельзя было выбирать. Добавил скрин в описание.